# How to get from Bucharest Romania to Sarajevo, Bosnia Herzegovina

Tags: trains, buses, romania, bucharest, bosnia

I will be with two other adults on my Eastern Europe Trip in September/October and I am having a very difficult time finding the best way to travel between Bucharest, Romania and Sarajevo, Bosnia Herzegovina.

We would like to do an overnight train, if possible, but would consider traveling by bus or private transfer.

Comment: Is time an issue? If you consider just one overnight train, I think you might be underestimating the distance and the time it takes to travel by train or bus in many East-European countries. There is a feasible train connection via Budapest and Zagreb, but it takes almost 48 hours and you have to spend a night in Zagreb.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't attempt to travel by train in Bosnia. Trains are often in bad condition and are more late than not, not to mention extremely slow. Best bet would be to try to find a bus route.

Comment: i would imagine bus to Belgrade and then another bus to Sarajevo

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get from Bucharest to Sarajevo on train - likely requiring a rather roundabout route via Budapest, Hungary and Zagreb, Croatia or even Salzburg, Austria an thus easily taking as much as 48h.

A [map of the railway lines in Europe](http://www.interrail.eu/plan-your-trip/interrail-railway-map) may be found on the [interrail website](http://www.interrail.eu/plan-your-trip) and their [timetable/trip planner](http://www.interrail.eu/plan-your-trip/interrail-timetable) will provide connections and times.

Entering Bucharest and Sarajevo as start and end of your travel may or may not yield the optimum connections - do play around with adding stops in between to see if you can manually figure out a better solution than the one initially suggested by the site.

If you're happy to consider other means of transport (i.e. bus) and/or mixing means of transport, this may become much easier, using the Budapest to Sarajevo bus. See [here](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bucharest/Sarajevo) for a useful site that allows comparisons of means of transport.

Comment: In my experience, the Bucharest - Budapest train isn't bad at all.  It does take about 16 hours.